# Replace string values in list

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a collection of strings which contain values like "goalXXvalue,goalXXLength,TestXX". It is a List(of String)
I thought I would be able to loop through each item and replace the XX value which I've tried with the method below but the values don't change. Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

`metricList.ForEach(Function(n) n.Replace("XX", "1"))`

Comment: In a single statement this would do the work: metricList = metricList.ConvertAll(s => s.Replace("XX", "1"));

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- first, strings are immutable, so when you call `.Replace` you return a new string. Calling `n.Replace` doesn't modify `n`.
- assigning to `n` in your anonymous function won't affect the value that's in your list.
- regardless of the above, you can't change the content of your collection while enumerating it, because it'll invalidate the enumeration.

Since it seems you're changing every string in your list, it seems unnecessary to try to modify the collection in-place. Therefore, the succint solution would be to use Linq would to create a new list:

```
var newList = metricList.Select(s => s.Replace("XX", "1")).ToList();
```

Comment: Since he stated that he's using a generic list I would suggest ConvertAll(), because it does not iterate twice over the collection like Select & ToList together.

Comment: Select doesnt iterate the list it just defines and enumerable that the two list iterates over. One iteration

Answer (score 15):

Problem: You aren't doing anything with the Replaced strings.
You could easily do this, using a simple loop:

**C#**

```
for(int i = 0; i < metricList.Count; i++)
{
    metricList[i] = metricList[i].Replace("XX", "1");
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
For i As Integer = 0 To metricList.Count - 1
    metricList(i) = metricList(i).Replace("XX", "1")
Next
```

Code iterates through all strings in `metricList` and replaces `XX` for `1`, it then stores the values back at the correct place in the list, what you aren't doing in your code...

Or using Linq:

**C#**

```
var newList = metricList.Select(x => x.Replace("XX", "1")).ToList();
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim newList = metricList.Select(Function(x) x.Replace("XX", "1")).ToList()
```

Don't forget to add a reference to linq at the top of your class:

**C#**

```
using System.Linq;
```

**VB.NET**

```
Imports System.Linq
```

Comment: The "ForEach" in your Linq version should be a "Select"

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign result of String.Replace method. So your func should return something or use instead of foreach select

Comment: You notice the cause here, but don't offer an option that solves it.

Comment: It is the option. You need to assign result of String.Replace method and use select means in code - .Select(x => x.Replace("a","b"))