# Linq String Replace

Tags: c#, linq

```
var arr = new[] {"A ", "B ", "C "}.ToList();
        arr.ForEach(a => a = a.Replace(" ", ""));
```

Why this does not remove space characters from the strings in the array?

This works `arr = arr.Select(a => a.Replace(" ", "")).ToList();`

Comment: ForEach does not modify the original collection, it only uses it as a source of inputs, your code is only updating the local variable to be without spaces, but those new values are not put back into the array.

Comment: `arr = arr.Select(a => a.Replace(" ", "")).ToList();`

Comment: @DavidG Duh, sorry, I misread your code and mixed it up with the OPs proposal; `arr = arr.Select(a => a.Replace(" ", ""))` which is hideous. Sorry about that, you are not mutating anything, simply doing a projection and reassigning `arr` which is the right apporach.

Comment: @DavidG plus 3rd week in lock down :( I'm going bonkers...

Comment: The only thing about LINQ in your question is the `.ToList()`. The .`ForEach` method is just a method on `List<>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace string values in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349387/replace-string-values-in-list) It seems to be an exact duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `a.Replace(..)` returns a (reference to) a new string. You do assign that new reference back to the local parameter `a`. However, that parameter `a` is a *copy* of the reference in the list. Updating `a` does *not* update the reference in the list itself.

If you want to update "in place", you will have to do it the old fashioned way:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.Count; i++)
{
    arr[i] = arr[i].Replace(" ", "");
}
```